# Can Touch of Destiny (Sp) be self cast?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, touch-attacks

The Sorcerer's Destined Bloodline gave at level 1 the Touch of Destiny ability.

> Touch of Destiny (Sp): At 1st level, you can touch a creature as a standard action, giving 
>   it an insight bonus on attack rolls, skill checks, ability checks, and saving throws equal 
>   to 1/2 your sorcerer level (minimum 1) for 1 round. You can use this ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Charisma modifier.

So the definition says that "You can touch a creature" but doesn't exclude you of the possible creatures. Am I misinterpreting, or can you indeed cast it on yourself?

I understand it would be pretty useless in fight, since you would have used your single action to buff yourself for one round (for a sorcerer level below 3), but could you use it to help in a skill check, like lockpicking out of fight?

Comment: Ok, so touch attack can be self cast, but can it give you buff for a skill check?

Comment: Of course it can.

Comment: A 1-round effect ends right before the creature's next turn and the creature's used a standard action to for touch of destiny, so that skill check better take only the creature's free, swift, or move action this turn or an immediate or off-turn free action (like speaking!) before its next turn or else the bonus'll be wasted.